# Is this a regular language?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, regular-language

This is the initial grammar:

```
S → ε | c | bSb | aAa
A → aSa | bAb
```

some resulting words are:

```
baabaabbbbaabaab
bcb
baabaacaabaab
bbaabcbaabb
ababbaba
bbbb
ababbcbbaba
baabcbaab
aaaacaaaa
aacaa
baaaaaacaaaaaab
bbbbaacaabbbb
abaaabbaaaba
abbbaaacaaabbba
```

At first I wrote this regular expression `(a|b)*c?(a|b)*` but later I noticed that the a and b occurrences are always even, so this regualr expression is wrong. Considering that an automata can't count, can I conclude that the language is not regular?   Thank you very much!

Comment: Your intuition is correct. DFAs, which decide regular languages, cannot keep any additional data other than what state the machine is in, so it's only able to "count" using states. A more formal way to express this is the pumping lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), which will let you find an example of a string of arbitrary length in your language that can be "pumped" into strings not in your language. A good example starting string would be `b^ncb^n`, because no matter how this string is pumped, the result isn't in your language.

Comment: @Welbog Thank you! If you don't mind, could you give me an example of a simple non-regular grammar that produce a regular language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This language is not regular. You can prove as much using the Myhill-Nerode theorem as follows. Consider the prefix `b^n c`. The shortest string which can be appended to this string to get a string in the language of the grammar is `b^n`; no shorter string can be appended to `b^n c` to get a string in the language. Imagine the language were regular. Then after processing the prefix `b^n c`, the DFA would have to have a shortest path to an accepting state of length `n`. But `n` is an arbitrary natural number and the DFA must have some fixed constant number of states. This is a contradiction, so our language has no DFA and is not regular.

An example of a non-regular grammar producing a regular language is trivially the following:

```
S -> aSa | aS | A | e
aSSaa -> Saa
A -> AA | ASA | aSaSA
SAS -> ASASSASaaSa
```

This is not regular, it's not even context-free. But it generates the regular language of all strings of a, `a*`, owing to productions `S -> aS | e` alone.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Your grammar is similar to the one you wrote me a few days ago. But seems to me that a non regular CFG to generate a regulare language has to be quite complex.

Comment: @cieco1109 A non-regular grammar doesn't have to be complicated to generate a regular language. I just wanted to show even non-context-free grammars can generate regular languages, too. Just take any old CFG and you can add a few rules to ensure it generates the regular language of all strings. S -> E, E -> all strings. This is especially easy with unary alphabets, e.g., E -> aE | empty.